# if statement in datagridview currentcell change

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, indexing, row

what is the correct condition to check the current row is changed when you move to the other cell.

I try this code:

```
Private Sub Legal_RecordsDataGridView_CurrentCellChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Legal_RecordsDataGridView.CurrentCellChanged

    if Legal_RecordsDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index = Legal_RecordsDataGridView.CurrentCellAddress.Y then

        msgbox("changed")
        else
        msgbox("no")

    endif
End Sub
```

I always get a result of "no" because they always have the same index.

How can I check if the `CurrentRow` index is the same when I move to the other cell for example when I move to the other cell but the same row I want a result of `no` but when I move to the other cell like if I'm at the column1 but I moved on column2 but different row then the result is `changed`

I hope you get what i mean!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try getting the row index after the CurrenCellChanged event..

for example..

```
Private Sub Legal_RecordsDataGridView_CurrentCellChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Legal_RecordsDataGridView.CurrentCellChanged

'Add the condition here..
'Say, what's the value of last row index? If you don't have a value for last row index, then exit sub


'get here the last row index (set the variable), this should give you the row index that you can use in your next cell change event..
mynewrowindex = Legal_RecordsDataGridView.currentrow.index

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

`mRow_Leave` is a Global variable

```
Dim mRow_Leave as integer


Private Sub DataGridView1_CurrentCellChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CurrentCellChanged

        If mRow_Leave = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex Then

            MsgBox("no")
        Else
            MsgBox("change")
        End If
        mRow_Leave = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex
    End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_RowLeave(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowLeave

   mRow_Leave = e.RowIndex

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Legal_RecordsDataGridView_CurrentCellChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Legal_RecordsDataGridView.CurrentCellChanged

    if Legal_RecordsDataGridView.cells.Index = Legal_RecordsDataGridView.CurrentCellAddress.Y then

        msgbox("changed")
        else
        msgbox("no")

    endif
End Sub
```